# MonkeyRunner on Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, monkeyrunner

[How does Python (or MonkeyRunner) locate imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115318/how-does-python-or-monkeyrunner-locate-imported-modules)

I previously asked about an error I get when running a `monkeyrunner` script from Git Bash. I still haven't resolved the issue and decided to try running it from the Windows 7 command line. I `cd` to the directory containing my `.py` files and run

> > monkeyrunner screenshots.py
>   Can't open specified script file
>   Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

```
-s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
-p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
-v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

`screenshots.py` is indeed in the current directory. Why can't monkeyrunner find it? What do I need to do to fix this to run on Windows 7?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @AndiJay It appears to be a bug in how Monkey Runner parses the python search path (see the "update" in the linked question). However, I have not found a solution to this problem on Windows. I primarily use Linux now which doesn't have this same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python (or MonkeyRunner) locate imported modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115318/how-does-python-or-monkeyrunner-locate-imported-modules)

Answer (score 0):

did you try giving full path to your screenshots.py.

> monkeyrunner C:\folder_location_to_your_file\scrrenshots.py

Comment: Thanks for the suguggestion. I'll give that a shot to see what happens. (Even if it loads `screenshots.py`, my guess is that it will still have issues loading my `util` module that it imports. One step at a time, though.)

Comment: from windows command-line you should be able to import custom modules if your folder structure is correct. I am sorry,i haven't tried from Git bash.Anyway keep posted, i can also learn. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to call `monkeyrunner` script if the `cmd` is in the directory that contains your script:

```
monkeyrunner "%cd%\your_script.py"
```

Make sure you put the `""` marks.

Comment: What the `cd` variable?

Comment: The %cd% referes to the current directory of the cmd, e.g. if your script is in C:\scripts folder and your cmd is in that directory, monkeyrunner "%cd%\script.py" would be the same as monkeyrunner "C:\scripts\script.py".